# Engine sound is not working perfectly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio-player

I'm working on a car game ;
  Where I'm getting the pitch value from my topspeed and current speed,but sound is very buggy.
Any solution ?

```
public float Topspeed=100;
void Update()
{
    AnalyzeSound();
}
public void carMovement()
{
    currentSpeed = wc [2].radius * wc [2].rpm * 60 / 1000 * Mathf.PI;
    currentSpeed = Mathf.Round (currentSpeed);
}
AnalyzeSound ()
{
    audio.pitch = currentSpeed / Topspeed;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'buggy'?  You mean glitches like it starting and stopping?

Comment: You might check out [Time.deltaTime](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html) just in case it's what the doctor ordered.

Comment: I tried to mean sound is not clear .It's sound  like a tractor!  @ Jim W

Comment: What happens when you drag the pitch slider for the audio source from 0 up, when in play mode? does it sounds "right" or does it still sound like a tractor? Is `carMovement()` actually being called somewhere? If not, it will remain at 0, which probably sounds tractorish.

Answer (score 0):

It doesnt looks like `carMovement` is being called. Add it in `Update()` so the value gets a chance to change.

```
public float Topspeed=100;
void Update()
{
    AnalyzeSound();
    carMovement();
}
```

Also you may want to look into using a formula similar to https://www.omega.com/techref/das/scaling.html to figure out how to scale your pitch, because you may want to limit the range that the pitch can operate at. ( Yours would use pitch and RPM, as opposed to the example that uses voltage and PSI... once you figure out M and B you slap it in like `pitch = M * RPM + B`)